# Possible coil pack issue. Cause?

Tags: ford, focus

I own a 2006 Ford Focus (petrol) with just over 88000 miles on the clock.

Two years ago the coil pack failed and had to be replaced.
One month after that, it was replaced again under warranty as the original replacement failed.

The car is now, once again, exhibiting the same symptoms as before and will be taken to the garage.

I am expecting that this is another coil pack failure, but what I am worried about is that this now seems to be a recurrent failure, leading me to suspect that the failing coil pack might be a sympom of a deeper problem.

What possible problem might lead to repeated coil pack failure?

Comment: What grade of part was it replaced with? Was it an OEM Motorcraft or FoMoCo part? Or was is an off brand replacement? Some economy replacement parts do not last long because they do not meet OEM specifications.

Comment: It wasn't a Ford branded part, I don't actually know the brand of the replacement unfortunately :(

Comment: Where are you located?  Perhaps in a hot weather area?

Comment: It's been hot for us, but UK hot isn't excessive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, the "coil pack" was used in the Focus until 2004, then they changed to individual coils on each spark plug. Do you have a coil pack, or individual coils? It sounds like, from your description, that you have a true coil pack, which means you have spark plug wires. If the wires are faulty, they will cause the coil pack to fail prematurely. Have them tested with and ohmmeter to make sure they have the correct resistance. Replace them if defective, along with the coil pack.

Comment: The car has been to the garage now, and they described it as the coil pack being split into two - with one of the two parts having failed.  Does that help identify it?

Comment: Yes, that means you should have spark plug wires. They need to be checked with an ohmmeter and replaced if they have high resistance. That can cause your recurring issue.